# using regular expressions find phrase in the file

Tags: java, regex

using regular expression for searching phrase in the file

```
So...

Task:

I have some phrase. the phrase contains 2 words. Phrase is devided into two words with next symbols:

[\s]*

How can i find the phrase using regular expression?

This code doesn't work on a file:
```

```
// file: Main.java
    class 


    Main {
    }
```

**program**

```
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("class[\\s]+Main");

          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader( "Main.java" ) );

          int id = 0;

          for ( String line = input.readLine(); line != null; line = input.readLine() )
          {
             ++id;

             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( line );


             if ( matcher.find() )
             {
                System.out.println("number = " + id );

                System.out.println("start = " + matcher.start() );
                System.out.println("end   = " + matcher.end() );
                System.out.println( );
             }
          }

          input.close();
```

Comment: Its not very clear, at least to me in one reading, what you are trying to do and what you want. Please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: <pre><code>Pattern.compile("class[\\s]+Main",Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTANY);</pre></code>

Comment: I try to find phrase in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to put the entire file into one string (add the string to a `StringBuilder` in your for loop, and then do one match on the result at the end), or you need to add a case where you store the last word on one line and the first word on the next line that has any words, and check those also.  The easiest but probably not fastest way to do this is something like:

```
String lastline = ""
// For loop begins
  String[] ll_parts = lastline.split("\\s")
  lastline = line;
  line = ll_parts[ll_parts.length-1] + line;
// Now do the match
```